# Ipad checkbox/radiobutton action slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad

I am developing a web application which will be accessed from an html container within a native IOS app. Currently I am testing functionality in safari which hopefully will be similar to the html container. One thing I noticed is that the click action on the checkbox selectors and radio buttons is painfully slow. My menu items were also experiencing this behavior when I was waiting for the 'click' action. Instead of listning for this I switched to the 'touchstart'

```
$("#rab-icon").on('touchstart', function () {
```

Is it possible to override the html functionality and select these radiobuttons/checkboxes on 'touchstart' ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue with the fastclick extension. https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick